# Insert string right before last '.' in string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this NSString:

```
@"aa.bb.cc.png"
```

I want to insert myString right before the .png to make

```
@"aa.bb.ccSTUFF.png"
```

Is there a better way to do this than to reverse iterate until '.' is found, then split at location, then add component1 + stuff + extension together?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *path = [originalPath stringByDeletingPathExtension];
path = [path stringByAppendingString:myString];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathExtension:[originalPath pathExtension]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression for that:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[.]([^.]*)$"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:&error];
NSString *res = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str
    options:0
    range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])
    withTemplate:@"STUFF.$1"];
```

The idea behind the regex is to match the last dot and the extension, and then replace with the additional string of your choice (`$1` in the replacement template means the content of the first capturing group, which corresponds to the  extension).

Comment: @Milo If you create the expression upfront, the amortized calls of `stringByReplacingMatchesInString` method by themselves would probably be less expensive than two appends, because each call does not create a throw-away object in between the two invocations. In the end, the difference in performance would likely not matter at all, so it's going to be a matter of personal preferences.